# ActiveAdmin create a custom filter based on getter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

I have an ActiveAdmin page with filters.
I would like to set a custom filter based on a getter (a method defined on the resource, not an ActiveRecord attribute).

```
class House
  def is_enchanted?
    # Ask to witches and ghosts...
  end
end
```

This is the ActiveAdmin resource:

```
ActiveAdmin.register House do
  filter :is_enchanted?
end
```

The above code raises the following exception:

```
undefined method `is_enchanted?_eq' for #<Ransack::Search:0xc188178>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use scopes

models/house.rb

```
class House
  scope :is_enchanted?, 
      #where(....) 
end
```

admin/house.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register House do
  scope :is_enchanted?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom Ransack search methods called "ransackers". There isn't any official documentation for it, so you'll need to do some searching on the Ransack issue tracker on GitHub for discussions like this one: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/36